# how to identify the third friday of a particular month using sas

Tags: sas

I have a time series data. Data looks like the following:

```
date            variable
01-Dec-2012     0.1
02-Dec-2012     0.1
03-Dec-2012     0.1
04-Dec-2012     0.1
05-Dec-2012     0.1
...
20-Dec-2012     0.1
21-Dec-2012     0.1
22-Dec-2012     0.1
```

I want to create a dummy variable which equals to 1 if date is in December and it is before or at the second Thursday. It equals to 0 if date is in December and after the second Thursday. It equals to missing if month(date) ^= 12.

Can anyone teach me how to identify the second Thursday of December and solve this problem please.

Comment: Have you looked att the date functions available? By using functions like month(date), Week(date) and day(date) then this should be quite easy.

Comment: If 1st day of the month falls on Friday, week(date) = 1 however this Thursday is not the first Thursday of the month. I am trapped here.

Comment: weekday() should help. Working on a solution.

Comment: Your subject line and last line ask for different things. Third Friday or second Tuesday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NWKDOM

Third Friday in a month, where the month /year are extracted from a SAS date.

```
Friday3 = NWKDOM(3, 6, month(sas_date), year( sas_date));
```

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/63354/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1kdveu0ry8ltxn1m3um2ntxs7d5.htm

Comment: im sure Reeza means Friday3 = NWKDOM(3, 6, month(sas_date), year( sas_date));
This seems to be the easiest solution and change if its thursdays your after and month=12.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach for people who don't have SAS 9.3+ and can't use `nwkdom` to do this:

```
Dummy = intck('week.5',intnx('month',date,0)-1,date-1) < 2;
```

How this works, from the inside working outwards:

1. `intnx` is used to find the first day of the month.
2. Subtract 1 to get the last day of the previous month.
3. Subtract 1 from `date` to get yesterday's date.
4. Using `intck`, count the number of Thursdays (`week.5`) in between these two dates. N.B. this includes yesterday if it was a Thursday, but **not** the last day of the previous month if *that* was a Thursday.
5. If this number is less than 2, `date` is currently less than or equal to  the second Thursday of the month.

Sample usage:

```
data _null_;
 do date = '01dec2011'd to '30dec2011'd;
  Dummy = intck('week.5',intnx('month',date,0)-1,date-1) < 2;
  put date weekdate. +1 dummy;
 end;
run;
```

EDIT: now works correctly when the first day of the month is a Thursday.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for all timeperiods. If the do loop starts one year earlier then the dummy identifies the third thursday (in dec 2011).

Comment: @Jonas Fixed, I think

Answer (score 0):

Think this will solve your problem. Have a feeling there is a nicer solution for this but it should work.

```
data YourData;
format date date9. ;
do i=1 to 100 ;
date=intnx('day', '17oct03'd,i);
var=rand('uniform');
output;
end;
drop i;
run;

Data Find;
set YourData;
Month=month(date);
day=day(date);
Weekday=WEEKDAY(date);

/* weekday=5 this is thursday */
if weekday=5 and month=12 then flag=1;

/* flag2 retains the value */
flag2+flag;

if month=12 and flag2 < 2 then Dummy=1;
else if month=12 and flag2=2 and flag=1 then Dummy=1;
else if month=12 then Dummy=0;
else Dummy=.;

run;
```